# Store if and else expression in database and execute the expression in javascript or node.js. How to achieve this?

Tags: node.js, expression

I want to store an expression in database and execute it in node.js. how i will achieve this? please help.

stored expression is below:

```
if(10>15){return 0;}else{return 1;}
```

Comment: Is this `if(10>15){return 0;}else{return 1;}` exact syntax you want to strore?

Comment: Can you kindly show what you have tried

Comment: var functionString = "(function whatever(a) { if(10>15){return 0;}else{return 'santosh';} })";

var x = eval(functionString);
console.log(x());

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? The one you are trying is working fine.

Comment: Is there any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use eval, you can create a Function instance as below.

```
var myFuncString = "if(10>15){return 0;}else{return 'santosh';}"
var myfunc = new Function(myFuncString);
myfunc();
```

Comment: Thanks all of you